# I can't understand how the time complexity of following c++ code is calculated?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, set

Following code prints union of two unsorted arrays using C++ STL set.
I know that the time complexity of inserting an element in a set is O(log N), where N is the size of the set.
This code is from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-union-and-intersection-of-two-unsorted-arrays/.

```
// C++ program for the union of two arrays using Set
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void getUnion(int a[], int n, int b[], int m)
{
 
    // Defining set container s
    set<int> s;

    // Inserting array elements in s
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      s.insert(a[i]);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
      s.insert(b[i]);
    cout << "Number of elements after union operation: " << s.size() << endl;
    cout << "The union set of both arrays is :" << endl;
    for (auto itr = s.begin(); itr != s.end(); itr++)
        cout << *itr
             << " "; // s will contain only distinct
                 // elements from array a and b
}

// Driver Code
int main()
{
    int a[9] = { 1, 2, 5, 6, 2, 3, 5, 7, 3 };
    int b[10] = { 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 4, 6, 5, 4 };

    getUnion(a, 9, b, 10);
}
```

**Time Complexity: O(m * log(m) + n * log(n))**.
Please explain how the above time complexity is calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, a `set` is internally implemented using a self-balancing Binary Search Tree (BST). This means that everytime a new element is inserted into a `set`, internally it has to check the correct place of insertion of this new element in the BST, and then rebalance that BST. This operation of inserting a new element and performing rebalance of the BST takes approximately `O(log(n))` time where `n` is the number of elements in the BST.

---

The below code snippet runs `n` times, and each `insert` operation has `O(log(n))` time complexity in the worst case, hence the time complexity of the below piece of code is `O(n * log(n))`.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      s.insert(a[i]);
```

---

Now, after the above code snippet is executed, the set will have `n` elements in the worst case (if all the `n` elements in `int a[]` are unique).

The next code snippet provided below runs `m` times, and each `insert` operation has `O(log(n + m))` time comlexity in the worst case (because there might already be `n` elements in the `set` before this below loop starts), hence the time complexity of the below piece of code is `O(m * log(m + n))`.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
      s.insert(b[i]);
```

---

This last for loop below runs for all the `n + m` elements in the worst case (if all the `n` elements in array `a[]` and all the `m` elements in array `b[]` are unique). Hence, the time complexity of the below code is `O(n + m)`, because the below code visits all the `n + m` elements in the internal BST.

```
    for (auto itr = s.begin(); itr != s.end(); itr++)
        cout << *itr
             << " "; // s will contain only distinct
                 // elements from array a and b
```

---

All the above 3 code snippets run serially (one after the other), hence the total time complexity has to be added to find the final time complexity.

Time Complexity = `O(nlog(n) + mlog(m + n) + (m + n))`

Out of all the above 3 terms, `nlog(n)` and `mlog(m + n)` terms are larger than `(m + n)`, hence we can omit `(m + n)` and write the time complexity as `O(nlog(n) + mlog(m + n))`.

---

Relevant Links -

- [GeeksForGeeks Article on `set` vs `unordered_set` in C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/set-vs-unordered_set-c-stl/)
- [GeeksForGeeks Article on Searching and Insertion in Binary Search Tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-set-1-search-and-insertion/)

Comment: Thanks. Now I completely understood how the time complexity of the above code is calculated.

Comment: Glad I could be of help, @SakshiHalge, please feel free to mark this answer as "Accepted".

Comment: Off course. This answer helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting a new element in set is in logarithmic time(in your case `O(log n)` and `O(log m)` ), so the total time complexity is `O(m * log(m) + n * log(n))` .

Here's [a link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_containers#Characteristics) you can refer.